# TinyMCE: How to add brush?

Tags: javascript, moodle, tinymce-4

I found at the [Moodle Docs](https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/TinyMCE_editor) that they use TinyMCE with the brush tool :

[image]

On the official TinyMCE
I found a full featured example of [TinyMCE including all plugins](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/full-featured/). However, I did not find the brush tool. I could also not find it in the [plugins section](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/) nor in the [editor control identifiers](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-control-identifiers/#toolbarcontrols).

How can I add the brush as it is done in Moodle?

Comment: @Mehdi your right, was a mistake. Thanks for mentioning. I removed it.

Comment: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@cleanup/

Comment: @j08691 so it was `cleanup` and they removed it in 3.4? I will check that out asap. Funny that they have a note `Notice: It's not recommended to disable this feature.` and then they remove it completely!

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the brush is the same as the [Format Painter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-format-painter-4bb415a9-d4e4-42b7-b579-170adc594e40) in word. I figured out that this is not the case, its purpose is to clean messy code. They removed it in version 3.4 (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@cleanup/, thanks to j08691) without giving a reason.

That is why I can't find the icon.

There exists some request for a Format Painter tool [here](https://community.tinymce.com/communityIdeaDetail?id=08761000000AT6wAAG) and [here](https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=906610000006C93AAE) so I guess it does not exists atm.